# Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Usage service application not found. error

Tags: health-analyzer, monitoring

I'm receiving this error on our SharePoint server in event viewer.

When I check the `Configure usage and health data collection` I see `WSS_Logging_fd8d31dd9b964a649407b44127593673` as the database name. When I check the database the DB is listed as `WSS_Logging` with no GUID attached to it.

If I try to `Enable usage data collection`, or make any changes at all, I receive the error:

> A Usage Application already exists in this farm

The service app does exist in the `Manage Service Applications` page.

I'm thinking this may have become corrupt. Is there any downsides or repercussions to recreating this service?

Comment: Run powershell `Get-SPServiceApplication` and check if you have multiple Usage Service Applications.

Comment: There is only one

Comment: Then I would suggest deleting that and recreating a new one. You can use Powershell to specify the database name.

Comment: Amal's suggestion ended up being the route I took, if you post an answer I will mark it.

Comment: MickB, I have converted my comments to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run powershell `Get-SPServiceApplication` and check if you have multiple Usage Service Applications.

Then I would suggest deleting that and recreating a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Please check  the account running the SharePoint tracing service, add it into the "Performance Log Users" group, and give it read/write permissions on the 15/Logs folder , then restart the SharePoint tracing serice.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to change the database used by your Usage service application ?

```
Set-SPUsageApplication -DatabaseServer <DatabaseServerName> -DatabaseName <DatabaseName>
```

You can try this as a farm's administrator and SPShellAdmin :

```
Set-SPUsageApplication -DatabaseServer <DatabaseServerName> -DatabaseName WSS_Logging
```